# 'Activate Features': Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, object-reference, sharepoint-feature, feature-activation

I have the following activation code:

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        // Create a new list and populate it.
        using (SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
        {
            web.Lists.Add("Projects", "Projects That are currently being worked on.", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
            web.Update();

            // Add the new list and the new content.
            SPList projectList = web.Lists["Projects"];
            projectList.Fields.Add("Name", SPFieldType.Text, false);
            projectList.Fields.Add("Description", SPFieldType.Text, false);
            projectList.Update();

            //Create the view? - Possibly remove me.
            System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection stringCollection = 
                new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
            stringCollection.Add("Name");
            stringCollection.Add("Description");

            //Add the list.
            projectList.Views.Add("Project Summary", stringCollection, @"", 100, 
                true, true, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Html, false);
            projectList.Update();
        }
    }
```

Which should go through and add a new list called project and its associated view. How ever when running the app I get:

> 'Activate Features': Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

My questions are:

- Why is this happening? The activation happens at a **site** level. and I am the **admin** of the "development" site.
- Should I be checking each time to make sure this list doesn't already exist? (each time, referring to each time I hit deploy)

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? That should be absolute first thing you look at, and it should be included in the question.

Comment: It actually doesn't say which line, It sais Line 0, Collumn 0, CustomerCommunicationProject. @jonSkeet

Comment: You don't have a full stack trace? Ick. Can you step through the code in a debugger? (If you're currently running the Release build, try the Debug build instead, which may well give you more information.)

Comment: Actually looking into that >.> How ever thats a whole other issue, apparently the debugger is not properly installed and thus I cant debug this type of code. One issue after another >.>

Comment: Well that's the first thing to fix. Trying to develop without a decent environment is not going to be fun. Sort that out, then come back to this issue.

Comment: I just work with what Im given

Comment: Change this line `properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb` to `(SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent` - does that give you an invalid cast exception instead? Life would definitely be easier if you fixed your environment first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have a Site scoped feature and that your `NullReferenceException` is being caused by you attempting to cast `properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb`.

If my assumption about your feature being Site scoped is correct you can't get access to an `SPWeb` the way you are trying. Try this instead:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    if (siteCollection != null) 
    {
        SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb;
        // Rest of your code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I continue with my using statement? Im not sure if that changes or not.

Comment: @TheWebs - no you don't need to dispose the root web, just dispose the site (I think).